Preventing duplicate entries in multiple columns from Userform
I have a table with address data. I enter these via a user form. AddressID, LastName, FirstName, ZipCode,City
When I click on the SaveButton, I want to check whether the address entered (without AddressID ) is already in the shAdress table.
For example
Up to now, I have been writing the data to the table and then checking for duplicates. However, it would make more sense to check the data before slicing. Can anyone help me with how to do this?



AddressID
LastName
FirstName
ZipCode
City





1
May
Paul
67105
Berlin



2
May
Paul
67106
Berlin
that's ok


3
May
Paul
67105
Berlin
this is wrong!



My function to check after insert in the sheet
Function CheckforDuplicateListObject(wksTab As Worksheet, TableName As String) As Boolean

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastRowNew As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vardat() As Variant

    'Switch off calculations
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    With wksTab
        .Activate
        
        'Number of rows and columns to be checked
        LastRow = .Range(TableName).Rows.Count
        LastCol = Range(TableName).Columns.Count
        
        'Form data field without ID column
        'Number of columns varies depending on the table!!!
        ReDim vardat(0 To LastCol - 2) As Variant
        
        For i = 2 To LastCol
            vardat(i - 2) = i
        Next i
        
        'Delete duplicate data records with comparison of the data field
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(TableName).DataBodyRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(vardat), Header:=xlYes
        
        'Number of remaining lines
        LastRowNew = .Range(TableName).Rows.Count
    End With
    
    ''Berechnungen wieder einschalten
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    If LastRowNew < LastRow Then
        CheckforDuplicateListObject = True
    Else
        CheckforDuplicateListObject = False
    End If
End Function


Sub testDuplikateListIbjectRows()

    If CheckforDuplicateListObject(shListobj, "tbAdressen") = False Then
        MsgBox "Die Daten wurden in die Tabelle eingetragen"
    Else
        MsgBox "Die Daten sind bereits vorhanden"
    End If
End Sub


Assuming you have a recent version of Excel, the following function will check for duplicates.
Function existDuplicates(arr As Variant) As Boolean

Dim vDat As Variant
vDat = WorksheetFunction.Unique(arr)

  If UBound(vDat) < UBound(arr) Then
    ' Duplicates Found!
    existDuplicates = True
  Else
    ' No Duplicates Found.
    existDuplicates = False
  End If

End Function

This could be applied to your situation as follows
Sub example()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    ' table with the data
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = wks.ListObjects("Address")

    ' get the data from the table
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = lo.DataBodyRange

    ' Only get the columns we need to check for the duplicates
    Set rng = rng.Columns("B:D")
    ' Increase the size by one empty row which gives
    ' the needed space in the array below to add the new record
    Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 1)

    ' Example
    Dim vDat As Variant
    vDat = rng.Value2
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = UBound(vDat)
   
    ' Add the data in question
    vDat(lastRow, 1) = "May"
    vDat(lastRow, 2) = "Paul"
    vDat(lastRow, 3) = 67105
  
    If existDuplicates(vDat) Then
        MsgBox "Duplicates Found!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No Duplicates Found"
    End If

End Sub

